# Why logistic regression example code does not port to linear regression example?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, linear-regression, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am looking at this tutorial: https://www.dataquest.io/mission/74/getting-started-with-kaggle

Following is the code for linear regression to predict, based on some variables, the survival of the titanic passengers.

```
# Import the linear regression class
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
# Sklearn also has a helper that makes it easy to do cross validation
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold

# The columns we'll use to predict the target
predictors = ["Pclass", "Sex", "Age", "SibSp", "Parch", "Fare", "Embarked"]

# Initialize our algorithm class
alg = LinearRegression()
# Generate cross validation folds for the titanic dataset.  It return the row indices corresponding to train and test.
# We set random_state to ensure we get the same splits every time we run this.
kf = KFold(titanic.shape[0], n_folds=3, random_state=1)

predictions = []
for train, test in kf:
    # The predictors we're using the train the algorithm.  Note how we only take the rows in the train folds.
    train_predictors = (titanic[predictors].iloc[train])
    # The target we're using to train the algorithm.
    train_target = titanic["Survived"].iloc[train]
    # Training the algorithm using the predictors and target.
    alg.fit(train_predictors, train_target)
    # We can now make predictions on the test fold
    test_predictions = alg.predict(titanic[predictors].iloc[test])
    predictions.append(test_predictions)

import numpy as np

# The predictions are in three separate numpy arrays.  Concatenate them into one.  
# We concatenate them on axis 0, as they only have one axis.
predictions = np.concatenate(predictions, axis=0)

# Map predictions to outcomes (only possible outcomes are 1 and 0)
predictions[predictions > .5] = 1
predictions[predictions <=.5] = 0

accuracy = sum(titanic["Survived"] == predictions)/len(predictions)

print (accuracy)
```

This is clear. For logistic regression is much easier:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation

# Initialize our algorithm
alg = LogisticRegression()
# Compute the accuracy score for all the cross validation folds.  (much simpler than what we did before!)
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(alg, titanic[predictors], titanic["Survived"], cv=3)
# Take the mean of the scores (because we have one for each fold)
print(scores.mean())
```

Now, why can't I do just, for LinearRegression:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation

# Initialize our algorithm
alg = LinearRegression()
# Compute the accuracy score for all the cross validation folds.  (much simpler than what we did before!)
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(alg, titanic[predictors], titanic["Survived"], cv=3)
# Take the mean of the scores (because we have one for each fold)
print(scores.mean())
```

This gives me a totally wrong result. Why is that? What is wrong in the last snippet of code?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are missing this mapping:

```
# Map predictions to outcomes (only possible outcomes are 1 and 0)
predictions[predictions > .5] = 1
predictions[predictions <=.5] = 0
```

Basically, what linear regression produces after a call to `predict` is a set of numbers (scores), then we need to manually map it back to class label. `cross_validation.cross_val_score` doesn't do the mapping for us, so what it ends up doing is comparing scores with class labels, which turns out to be bad.

On the other hand, `predict` of logistic regression gives us the class label ([Reference](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict))

Comment: I thought of that, but since I am comparing this to a set of 1 and 0, my score should be 0 (since most results won't be 0 or 1), but I get 0.3 instead of 0.8, and 0.3 is still much higher than 0

Comment: I re-run your script and I only got 0.13 as mean accuracy.

Comment: From the page I linked I get: 0.787878787879
[ 0.78451178  0.78787879  0.79124579]

Comment: and 0.374682056691
[ 0.33211124  0.39263029  0.39930464] for linear regression

Comment: how do you deal with missing value?

Comment: I followed the tutorial. For example, for age, I take the median and then fill that for all missing values.

Comment: You can check your predictions in the first snippet (before the mapping) to see how many values are actually 0